# Replicating full iPhone Screen Capture Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation

Follow up / related to previous question I'm 
 having [AVFoundation Issue Capturing Still Image with Overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234801/avfoundation-issue-capturing-still-image-with-overlay)

I'm working on a snapchat style application that uses AVFoundation and I was having some issues taking the picture. I'm capturing the UI and the overlay but not the camera feed. I'm trying to re-approach the picture capture by programmatically performing a screenshot.

```
//screenshot
func takePicture2(view: UIView)-> UIImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!,nil,nil,nil)
    return image!
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) 
{
    print("Taking Picture")

    let image = takePicture2(view:(UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view)!)
    shareIMG(image: image)
}
```

My question is this: how do I perform a capture similar to the iPhone manual screen capture (power and home button)? Manually screen capturing works in capturing the whole image and the camera feed. This method is currently capturing the app UI and overlay while not capturing the OS UI bar at the top. Which view should I use to get everything as if I was manually capturing a screenshot?

Comment: Any reason you are not using AVCapturePhotoOutput and creating a UIImage from that and applying your overlay to the cUIImage?

Comment: I'm using AVCaptureStillImageOutput because of target device OS is not up to date. Currently I'm having some issues with the captureStillImageAsynchronously